# Sort UITableView by text width iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, xcode4.5

I'm trying to populate a `UITableView` with an array in a particular order.

So far I can change the order in these ways

- alphabetically
- character count
- I can run loops to reverse the strings in the array and then display those.
- I can flip all these backwards, upside down etc.

But I can't seem to sort them by character width.
Not all fonts are monospaced, and I'd like to try sorting them by how much room the text in each cell takes up.

Is there a way to possibly do this?

Is it within the array? Or the tableCell? Or the Table itself?
I have all my data stored in a `NSMutableArray`.

Searches have come up with nothing so far. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To calculate the width of text use the following:**

```
CGSize sizeToFit = [rowText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] 
  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

. . . where the 220.0f is the width of your table cell.

As another answer describes, you can then add a size property (or associative reference) to your model. And then sort using this property:

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleSorter= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"yourWidthProperty"     
  ascending:YES];  
[arrayOfObjects sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:titleSorter];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can order your UITableView's cells any way to want to, but you have to do it before showing them, when you create the table's data source. If you use an NSFetchResultsController, you can put the distance as the sort descriptor. And if you are using a simple NS(Mutable)Array, sort it before making it the table's source.

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleSorter= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Your_Key" ascending:YES];
```

for NSArray:

```
[arrayOfObjects sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:titleSorter];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do animated sorting, take a look at the [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) library on GitHub. It can do animated sorting and filtering with with plain arrays or `NSFetchRequest`.

Run the "Sort" example project. I added it for your specific problem of sorting alphabetically or by length.

**Edit:** Here is a [direct link](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Sort/Sort/SortTableViewController.m) to the Sort example's table view controller source code.